# Python opencv :1036: error : (-215) mask.size == src1.size in function binary_op

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

[image]Hello I am running the python opencv code below on a raspberry pi 3 and using a usb camera.The program tracks a persons face and overlays a mask image over the face. My program keeps crashing and showing the error below:. Also the image masking the persons face is not removing the background color to just leave the image mask. Hope you can help.

:1036: error : (-215) mask.size == src1.size in function binary_op

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade_files/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

face_mask = cv2.imread('../images/mask_skull.png')
h_mask, w_mask = face_mask.shape[:2]

if face_cascade.empty():
    raise IOError('Unable to load the face cascade classifier xml file')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
scaling_factor = 0.5

while True:
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor,      interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
  for (x,y,w,h) in face_rects:
      if h > 0 and w > 0:
        h, w = int(1.4*h), int(1.0*w)
        y -= 0.1*h
        frame_roi = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
        face_mask_small = cv2.resize(face_mask, (w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        gray_mask = cv2.cvtColor(face_mask_small, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, mask = cv2.threshold(gray_mask, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
        masked_face = cv2.bitwise_and(face_mask_small, face_mask_small, mask=mask)
        masked_frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame_roi, frame_roi, mask=mask_inv)
        frame[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.add(masked_face, masked_frame)

cv2.imshow('Face Detector', frame)

c = cv2.waitKey(1)
if c == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The images you pass into one of the bitwise functions are not the same size, as the message hints. Print out the shapes and display/save all the intermediate images to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Hello. I  am just getting started using  opencv.  Can you please give me more details with some seudo code or code edits. So I can understand. For example where to put the print shape etc. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the problem is probably in one of the `cv2.bitwise_and` calls. So add `print(face_mask_small.shape)` and `print(mask.shape)` before the line where you create `masked_face`. Do something similar before the line where you create `masked_frame`.

Comment: Hello. So I added print("small mask",face_mask_small.shape) and print("mask",mask.shape) . Just below ret, mask = cv2.threshold(gray_mask, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  :  small mask outputs 151,108, 3 mask outputs: 168,120 but these numbers keep changing. as face moves in video until the sudden crash with the :1036: error : (-215) mask.size == src1.size in function binary_op error. What can I do ?

Comment: There you go. According to [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) `bitwise_and` needs two arrays of same size. 151x108 and 168x120 are not the same size.

Comment: BTW, don't you get a traceback? That would point you to the exact line where the problem is happening..

Comment: Ok. but for some reason the numbers are not constant . 168, 120 and 168,120 change as the camera or object moves on the camera. Don't understand what that means. I can change mask image size to match but not sure about the changing numbers from the print?

Comment: You need to debug your program. I've shown you one technique, you can save the intermediate images with `cv2.imwrite(...)`, use some interactive debugger, etc. Don't run the algorithm in an infinite loop, just do one iteration at a time and identify the scenario which causes problems. Read the documentation and try to understand each step, and find out where the result differs from your expectation. This is starting to get way too broad, you need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hello Dan Thank you very much . I will keep working on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107420/discussion-between-tonderai-ratisai-and-dan-masek).